# Spring. JUnit5. WebClient. How to test async calls

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, webclient, junit-jupiter

I have a Spring boot project with a service, which basically calls a private method, which does:

```
webClient.post().uri().accept(...).body(...).exchange()
```

and then puts a `subscribe(...)` on it, which simply logs the result.

Everything works fine, but now I need to test this, and this is where things start to get interesting.

By far, I've tried MockServer, okhttp, Spring's WebMockServer(or something), and only MockServer was willing to work at some point properly, while okhttp latest wants junit.rules.* (which is problematic to 
achieve), WebMockServer specifically wants RestTemplate.

Google does give out examples, in which a webClient logic method is left without a `.exchange()` call, giving a chance to call `.block()` in the test, but I'm not willing to expose a private method just in order to workaround the async calls.

Currently I'm struggling with DEEP_STUB strategy of Mockito to mock out the actual webClient chain, but this fails to work from the box, and I'm trying to make it work while writing this question.

So the question is - is there a proper way to test a webClient with an async call (maybe a MockServer with a timeout to the verification or something)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, @AppleBuckler?

Answer (score 0):

Wiremock seem to be an accepted way of mocking external http servers and it is now part of spring test framework.
Here is an introduction: https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock

Otherwise WebTestClient is a bean which might come in handy at this point if you can inject it in the constructor of your service class?

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebClient
class DemoResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        webTestClient = webTestClient
            .mutate()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .build();
    }

    @Test // just for reference
    void some_test_that_gives_success() {
        webTestClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/world")
                .queryParam("requestString", "hello")
                .build())
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(String.class);
    }
}
```